# angularjs ngrepeat img embed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning Angular since yesterday so the following may or may not make sense:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="social in socialnets">
    <a href="{{social.url}}" target="_blank">
       <img src="{{social.img}}" alt="{{social.alt}}" height="50">
       {{social.name}}
     </a>
</div>
```

the console is showing an error

```
GET http://10.0.0.27/%7B%7Bsocial.img%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

meaning to me:

```
<img src="{{social.img}} ...>
```

does this mean that it is triggered once before angularjs loads the scope variable ????

the page still renders ok. but.... What is the best way to remove the unneeded error?

makes no sense to me as the above ng-repeat is loaded by a ng-include

```
<div ng-include="'html/socialbar.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ng-src instead of src in your img tags.

```
<img ng-src="{{social.img}} ...>
```

Comment: @crlshn no problem, turns out the browser tries to be smart with img tags and tries to immediately load whatever is in the src so using ng-src makes it so some JS in angular can handle loading the image and avoiding the initial request before the interpolation has been processed